# How can I combine three functions that are nearly the same?

Tags: vb.net, function

I have 3 different functions, that are basically the same, except for one part (`ENTERHERE` in Code). Either `LastWriteTime`, `LastAcccessTime` or `CreationTime`.

```
Public Sub DeleteByENTERHERE(delDirectory As String)

    Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(delDirectory)
    For Each dctFile As IO.FileInfo In directory.GetFiles()
        If dctFile.ENTERHERE.AddDays(Owner.PluginXML.DeleteDays) < Now Then 
            Try
               dctFile.Delete()
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
    Next

    If Owner.PluginXML.DeleteInSubfolders Then
        For Each folder As IO.DirectoryInfo In directory.GetDirectories()
            DeleteByENTERHERE(folder.FullName)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I have a config menu in where I can decide which of the 3 functions I want to use and use this code to use/not use a function.

```
If Not Owner.PluginXML.LastWriteTime Then                                                   
    Exit Sub
End If
```

How can I combine the 3 functions into one? I tried something like this, but it doesn't feel like a clean solution.

```
    If Owner.PluginXML.LastWriteTime Then
        If file.LastWriteTime.AddDays(Owner.PluginXML.DeleteDays) < Now Then
        End If
    End If

    If Owner.PluginXML.LastAccessTime Then
        If file.LastAccessTime.AddDays(Owner.PluginXML.DeleteDays) < Now Then
        End If
    End If

    If Owner.PluginXML.CreationTime Then
        If file.CreationTime.AddDays(Owner.PluginXML.DeleteDays) < Now Then
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend three separate methods for the interface but the bulk of the implementation in a single private method, e.g.

```vb
Public Sub DeleteByLastWriteTime(folderPath As String)
    DeleteByFileTime(folderPath, FileTimeType.LastWrite)
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteByLastAccessTime(folderPath As String)
    DeleteByFileTime(folderPath, FileTimeType.LastAccess)
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteByCreationTime(folderPath As String)
    DeleteByFileTime(folderPath, FileTimeType.Creation)
End Sub

Private Enum FileTimeType
    LastWrite
    LastAccess
    Creation
End Enum

Private Sub DeleteByFileTime(folderPath As String, fileTimeType As FileTimeType)
    Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)

    For Each file In folder.EnumerateFiles()
        Dim fileTime As Date

        Select Case fileTimeType
            Case FileTimeType.LastWrite
                fileTime = file.LastWriteTime
            Case FileTimeType.LastAccess
                fileTime = file.LastAccessTime
            Case FileTimeType.Creation
                fileTime = file.CreationTime
        End Select

        If fileTime.AddDays(Owner.PluginXML.DeleteDays) < Date.Now Then
            file.Delete()
        End If
    Next

    If Owner.PluginXML.DeleteInSubfolders Then
        For Each subfolderPath In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folderPath)
            DeleteByFileTime(subfolderPath, fileTimeType)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

You might even refactor that private method into two:

```vb
Private Sub DeleteByFileTime(folderPath As String, fileTimeType As FileTimeType)
    Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)

    For Each file In folder.EnumerateFiles().Where(Function(fi) GetFileTime(fi, fileTimeType).AddDays(Owner.PluginXML.DeleteDays) < Date.Now)
        file.Delete()
    Next

    If Owner.PluginXML.DeleteInSubfolders Then
        For Each subfolderPath In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folderPath)
            DeleteByFileTime(subfolderPath, fileTimeType)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetFileTime(file As FileInfo, fileTimeType As FileTimeType) As Date
    Select Case fileTimeType
        Case FileTimeType.LastWrite
            Return file.LastWriteTime
        Case FileTimeType.LastAccess
            Return file.LastAccessTime
        Case FileTimeType.Creation
            Return file.CreationTime
        Case Else
            Throw New ArgumentException($"'{fileTimeType}' is not a valid {NameOf(fileTimeType)} value.", NameOf(fileTimeType))
    End Select
End Function
```